# Wordpress | Writing custom APIs for ajax calls or reports

Tags: wordpress

If I have to develop a simple custom API to be accessed directly say, to display "Hello World!", then what all steps I need to do?
Let's say the APIs reside in [/themes/my_theme/_apis/]

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to functions.php of your theme file and then write this :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_theme_ajax_method', 'my_theme_ajax_method');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_theme_ajax_method', 'my_theme_ajax_method');

function my_theme_ajax_method(){
   return 'Hello World'
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_frontend_custom_scripts' );

function my_theme_frontend_custom_scripts(){
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'MyTheme', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'action' => array (
            'MyAjaxMethod' => 'my_theme_ajax_method',
            )
        ) );
}
```

And then in your frontend consider index.php you can write this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery.ajax ({
                type : 'get',
                url : MyTheme.ajaxurl,
                data : {
                    action : MyTheme.action.MyAjaxMethod,
                },
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data); // <-- prints hello world
    })

});
```

Comment: hey mate. can you give me ur mail id or something. i am using your paytm package and i have some doubts